# How to replace 'special' characters in a string of code with an expanded piece of that same code?

Tags: javascript, replace, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that basically finds a string of text such as this (note the different numbers):

```
id%22%3A99986%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1002938%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22
```

and then usese javascript to swap that text above with this:

```
id%22%3A77764%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A77984%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A87746%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22
```

I can't manage to make this work whatsoever. All I'm able to do is swap out the ID numbers and replace individual parts of the code whereas I want to improve it by replacing with larger pieces of code. Can someone help me get past this because I'm confused.

Here is the code that works for me:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/99986/g, '77764');
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace one piece of code with two pieces of code (obviously wrong but it's clear what I'm trying to do):

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/id%22%3A99986%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22/g, 'id%22%3A77764%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A77984%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22');
```

Update 1:

Thank you Emeeus, your code worked great! Unfortunately I made an error in my example so I had to fix it up a bit from my end. This is the new code using your layout:

```
 var strA = 
"%7Bid%22%3A1001%2C%22name%22%3A%22The+Antique+Store%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1010%2C%22name%22%3A%22Clothes%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1349%2C%22name%22%3A%22Old+Store%22%7D";

    var strB = "%7Bid%22%3A1001%2C%22name%22%3A%22The+Modern+Store%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1010%2C%22name%22%3A%22Clothes%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1349%2C%22name%22%3A%22New+Store%22%7D";

    var arrA = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(',{""' + strA + '",:""}'));

    var arrB = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(',{""' + strB + '",:""}'));

console.log(arrA)
console.log(arrB)

var res = Object.assign(arrA, arrB);

console.log(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(res)))
```

But I'm met with this error "Error: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 0". Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need the first `,` and the first parameter is wrong, you could use something like `decodeURIComponent('['+strA+']').replace(/\{id"/g,'{"id"')`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check if the typeof string you are trying to replace is string. I tested, check if that solves your problem.

See screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are parts of a JSON [URI-encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), so I suggest first to decode the strings an then parse them using `JSON.parse`, then you could work with objects literals, which is easier most of times, here an example:

```js
var strA = "id%22%3A99986%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1002938%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22";

var strB = "id%22%3A77764%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A77984%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A87746%2C%22name%22%3A%22null%22%7D%2C%7B%22";

var arrA = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent('[{"' + strA + '":""}]'));

var arrB = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent('[{"' + strB + '":""}]'));


console.log(arrA)
console.log(arrB)

var res = Object.assign(arrA, arrB);//<-- example

console.log(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(res)))//<-- you could encode the result again
```

Comment: removed, please see original post